# Azure Devops event driven Automation

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, devops

Is there a way to listen to Workitems creation event in Azure Devops to programmatically perform follow on actions?

I can poll the Azure Devops Area Path for new work items and take actions but wanted to see if this can be performed in an event driven fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps provides a way to achieve this using Service Hooks - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops